# python lxml findall with multiple namespaces

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, xml-namespaces

I'm trying to parse an XML document with multiple namespaces with lxml, and I'm stuck on getting the findall() method to return something.

My XML:

```
<MeasurementRecords xmlns="http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         
                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07 RSP_EWS_V1.6.xsd">
    <HistoryRecords>
        <ValueItemId>100_0000100004_3788_Resource-0.customId_WSx Data Precip Type</ValueItemId>
            <List>
                <HistoryRecord>
                    <Value>60</Value>
                    <State>Valid</State>
                    <TimeStamp>2016-04-20T12:40:00Z</TimeStamp>
                </HistoryRecord>
            </List>
        </HistoryRecords>
    <HistoryRecords>
</MeasurementRecords>
```

My code:

```
from lxml import etree
from pprint import pprint

RSPxmlFile = '/home/user/Desktop/100_0000100004_3788_20160420144011263_records.xml'

with open (RSPxmlFile, 'rt') as f:
    tree = etree.parse(f)

root = tree.getroot()

for node in tree.findall('MeasurementRecords', root.nsmap):
    print node
    print "parameter = ", node.text
```

Gives:

```
ValueError: empty namespace prefix is not supported in ElementPath
```

Some experiments I've tried after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920073/how-to-use-xpath-from-lxml-on-null-namespaced-nodes):

```
>>> root.nsmap
{'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', None: http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07'}

>>> nsmap['foo']=nsmap[None]
>>> nsmap.pop(None)
'http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07'
>>> nsmap
{'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'foo': 'http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07'}
>>> tree.xpath("//MeasurementRecords", namespaces=nsmap)
[]
>>> tree.xpath('/foo:MeasurementRecords', namespaces=nsmap)
[<Element {http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07}MeasurementRecords at 0x6ffffda5290>]
>>> tree.xpath('/foo:MeasurementRecords/HistoryRecords', namespaces=nsmap)
[]
```

But that didn't seem to help.

So, more experiments:

```
>>> tree.findall('//{http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07}MeasurementRecords')
[]
>>> print root
<Element {http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07}MeasurementRecords at 0x6ffffda5290>
>>> print tree
<lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x6ffffda5368>
>>> for node in tree.iter():
...     print node
...
<Element {http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07}MeasurementRecords at 0x6ffffda5290>
<Element {http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07}HistoryRecords at 0x6ffffda5cf8>
<Element {http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07}ValueItemId at 0x6ffffda5f38>
...etc...
>>> tree.findall("//HistoryRecords", namespaces=nsmap)
[]
>>> tree.findall("//foo:MeasurementRecords/HistoryRecords", namespaces=nsmap)
[]
```

I'm stumped. I have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you start with this:

```
>>> tree = etree.parse(open('data.xml'))
>>> root = tree.getroot()
>>>
```

This will fail to find any elements...

```
>>> root.findall('{http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07}MeasurementRecords')
[]
```

...but that's because `root` *is* a `MeasurementRecords` element; it
does not *contain* any `MeasurementRecords` elements.  On the other
hand, the following works just fine:

```
>>> root.findall('{http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07}HistoryRecords')
[<Element {http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07}HistoryRecords at 0x7fccd0332ef0>]
>>>
```

Using the `xpath` method, you could do something like this:

```
>>> nsmap={'a': 'http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07',
... 'b': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'}
>>> root.xpath('//a:HistoryRecords', namespaces=nsmap)
[<Element {http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07}HistoryRecords at 0x7fccd0332ef0>]
```

So:

- The `findall` and `find` methods require `{...namespace...}ElementName` syntax.
- The `xpath` method requires namespace prefixes (`ns:ElementName`), which it looks up in the provided `namespaces` map.  The *prefix* doesn't have to match the prefix used in the original document, but the *namespace url* must match.

So this works:

```
>>> root.find('{http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07}HistoryRecords/{http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07}ValueItemId')
<Element {http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07}ValueItemId at 0x7fccd0332a70>
```

Or this works:

```
>>> root.xpath('/a:MeasurementRecords/a:HistoryRecords/a:ValueItemId',namespaces=nsmap)
[<Element {http://www.company.com/common/rsp/2012/07}ValueItemId at 0x7fccd0330830>]
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much.
Is it possible to return the `Value` node from exactly one `ValueItemId` element? 
I tried this, but it didn't work:

`root.xpath('/a:MeasurementRecords/a:HistoryRecords[a:ValueItemId="100_0000100004_3788_Resource-0.customId_WSx Data Precip Type"]//a:Value',namespaces=nsmap)`

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006283/xpath-select-first-element-with-a-specific-attribute) might help.