# Why my xpath query in xml file does not work?

Tags: python, xml, xpath

I have huge xml and need xpath query to "ПланыСтроки" and other similar elements

I open xml in firefox and copy xpath of node:

```
/Документ/diffgr:diffgram/dsMMISDB/ПланыСтроки[1]
```

and it does not work (i tested in https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester, but and in python-lxml (when I need run that code) some results).

The query runs well before the node

```
/Документ/diffgr:diffgram
```

and after that nothing match...

XML:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19VQA-PpslQmcwdz-40MQ7cysDTvO7p_r/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dsMMISDB element is in a namespace. Search for "XSLT default namespace" (there are about 700 hits, because so many people hit this problem) for a solution.

Comment: Thanks. I find soluten on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920073/how-to-use-xpath-from-lxml-on-null-namespaced-nodes

Comment: I create this "virtual namespace" for XSLT default namespace in <dsMMISDB xmlns="http://tempuri.org/dsMMISDB.xsd"> and use xpath like this "//*/virtual_NS:ПланыСтроки"